# GeoServer: Link meta data to raster image?

Tags: geoserver, raster, boundless-suite, image-mosaic

I want to use the OpenGeo Suite to publish different sets of raster imagery with associated data. Doing this with vectorial data works fine:

1. Setup the data base in postGIS: import the vectorial data, create tables containing data describing the objects.
2. Setup a data store in GeoServer: make a connection to the data base.
3. Setup a layer in GeoServer: combine vectorial data and attributes with a SQL view.

After that I understood that I can easily access attributes via `GetFeature` requests to a WFS. However, the same with raster data instead of vectorial data seems not to work like that. One can import raster data from postGIS (via the ImageMosaicJDBC plugin) but I see no means to link it in the same way as above.

I'm new to web mapping, so: Is it my ignorance of the matter or the lack of a feature in GeoServer?

Comment: How would one connect non spatial data to a raster image? Can you explain? Do you mean that you have a classified image like say Land Use, or zoning in a city?

Comment: Sorry I used the term "non spatial data" in a wrong sense. I wanted to say "meta data on the vectorial/raster data". Edited the question on that.

Answer (score 3):

The raster analog to WFS is WCS, the Web Coverage Service. The analog to GetFeature would be GetCoverage. The principles of WFS and WCS are the same (serving of raw spatial data), but the implementations are slightly different, as one deals with vectors and one deal with rasters.

GeoServer has some documentation on WCS here:

- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wcs/reference.html

I'm not sure about the "non-spatial" aspect of your question, but perhaps this will get you a bit further.

Comment: Ah right, I have somehow overlooked WCS. Thanks! Also, I have used the term "non-spatial data" in a wrong sense, I meant simply meta data to the vectorial/raster data. Edited the question on that. Looking at your link, I'm confused that for GetFeature they state "Returns a selection of features from a data source including geometry AND ATTRIBUTE VALUES" while with GetCoverage there is not mentioned anything about attributes. Can I really only query the coverage with GetCoverage?